# Do something before AVAudioPlayer play

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have a problem with AVAudioPlayer.
I want to color a cell of UICollectionView before the sound play, but with this code I'm not be able to do this operation.

I suppose that the operation that change the background is more slowly than the instruction that play sound, and for this reason the cell don't change background color.

```
int randomNumber = (arc4random() % [soundArray count]);
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[soundArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber] error:&error];
self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
if(!self.audioPlayer){
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
}
 else{
    CGColorRef colorRef = [[cellArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber] backgroundColor];
    [[cellArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber] setBackgroundColor:(__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor blackColor])];

    [self.audioPlayer play];
    sleep([self.audioPlayer duration]);

    [[cellArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber] setBackgroundColor:colorRef];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all I'm assuming that in the title of your question with "after" you are meaning "before".

However, I think your issue is connected with the use of the `sleep()` function. The problem with it is that it blocks the execution for the amount of time you specify. All the UI modifications in iOS (including the one to your background color) are not executed immediately, but when you return control to the current RunLoop (to say it horribly roughly, just to make you understand: *sometime after your method returns*). By using sleep you are delaying every update, and this causes the issue.
Sleep is not what you want to use, generally, because you really don't want to block the execution!

What I suggest you is to get rid of sleep and use - for example - `NSTimer`s instead: they do not block anything. Or, you can turn your attention to the delegate mechanism of `AVAudioPlayer` (as John Woods said) in order to reset your background color when you're done playing.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you're trying to do is to make your class an AVAudioPlayerDelegate and to use

```
audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:
```

That method is called automatically by the system right when the player finishes. It will give you the most reliable and efficient performance overall.

Comment: my problem is the operation before the play instruction. The operation after play instruction work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:songItem];

You can set Notification Center..it will fire after Song finish the playing..."itemDidFinishPlaying" is the method that you want to call...songItem is the AVPlayerItem..